# python get normal username from the root user?

Tags: python, ubuntu

When I want a user in Python3, from terminal

`sudo su`

`python3`

`>>> import getpass`

`>>>getpass.getuser()`

`'root'`

**how can I get the normal username?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the `os.getlogin()` from @bromate's answer.

Here is another way:

```
import os
user = os.environ['SUDO_USER'] # KeyError if not run under sudo
```

Comment: Great, it's working. Thanks
Its return my normal user name.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the script interactively, you should be using `sudo` to run it and `os.getlogin()` will give the correct user.

Comment: I am not using `sudo` why because I running on `root` user